# Explanation of method for finding basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The method of row reduction allows you to find a basis for a subspace just by placing the vectors as rows of a matrix and then row reducting it. I've always took a linear combination of the vectors, made it equal to $0$ and found out if the set were or were not linear independent. If yes, then it's a basis, if not, then I should remove one vector and try again.

But why the row reduction Works? I know that it's because row replacement and rows linear combinations don't change the space. But could somebody explain it better for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The act of using row operations on the rows of a matrix gives a new matrix whose rows are a linear combination of the rows of the original matrix.  The method of finding the reduced row echelon form ensures that the resulting non-zero rows are linearly independent.  They span the same subspace because they are a linear combination of the original rows.  Thus they span the space and are linearly independent and so form a basis of that subspace.